# Strange Behavior: Floating Point Error after Appending to List

Tags: python, python-2.7, behavior

I am writing a simple function to step through a range with floating step size. To keep the output neat, I wrote a function, `correct`, that corrects the floating point error that is common after an arithmetic operation.

That is to say: `correct(0.3999999999)` outputs `0.4`, `correct(0.1000000001)` outputs `0.1`, etc.

Here's the body of code:

```
floats = []  
start = 0  
end = 1  
stepsize = 0.1  
while start < end:
    floats.append(start)
    start = correct(start + stepsize)
```

The output, in the end, looks as if it hasn't been corrected:
`[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6,   0.7, 
0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]`

To check this, I inserted a print-statement to see what's being appended:

```
floats = []  
start = 0  
end = 1  
stepsize = 0.1  
while start < end:
    print start
    floats.append(start)
    start = correct(start + stepsize)
```

And the output of these print-statements is:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

So I know that the `correct` function is working properly. Thus, it appears that when `start` is appended to `floats`, something happens in the assignment that causes the floating-point error to flare up again.

Things get worse. I assign the variable `z` to the output, i.e. `z = [0,0.1,...]`. I try `print z`, which prints, as expected, the output that looks uncorrected:

`[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6,   0.7, 
0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]`

Now I try `for a in z: print a`. This prints out:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

But this doesn't correspond to the output in `print z`: one of them has floating-point error, the other doesn't.

Finally, I try `print [correct(x) for x in z]`. I get the uncorrected-looking output again.

I hope I've made clear the confusion I'm experiencing. Why does printing the list look so different from printing each item individually? Why are variables in a list unaffected by the `correct` function? I expect that this is due to some internal memory representation of floating point numbers in lists?

Finally, how can I ensure that the output is simply `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]`?

I am using Python 2.7.9.

Comment: can you provide the code for correct function also ?

Comment: @sachinsaxena I'm not sure if that will be helpful -- I've tested it extensively, it works perfectly. Why do you think it might matter -- as a consequence of a lazy-evaluation bug or something like that?

Comment: i am asking so that i can replecate the code for testing it

Comment: Run `print 0.30000000000000004`, and you may be surprised by what you see.

Comment: @user2357112 So I'm assuming that the print-statement cleans up floating point error to make it more human-readable?

Comment: It does not "clean up floating-point error". Doing so is impossible. `print` on Python 2 truncates floats to a maximum of 12 displayed significant digits.

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't know that -- thanks. Could you please look at Klaus D.'s answer? I left a comment there that I would like answered. Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I assume you print the resulting list `floats`. Printing a list will show the `repr` of the elements, not the `str`. Printing a single element (like in your second code sample) will show the `str` representation. They obviously differ. So your convert() works for the `str` part, but probably not for the `repr` part.

Comment: You really should show the code for `correct`; without that, this question is asking about what goes on inside a black hole (sorry, but your statement "So I know that the correct function is working properly" isn't really valid, since you're the only one who knows that code. If you have a problem here, why can't it be in convert()?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: your `correct` doesn't work.

Long answer:
The binary floating-point formats in ubiquitous use in modern computers and programming languages cannot represent most numbers like 0.1, just like no terminating decimal representation can represent 1/3. Instead, when you write 0.1 in your source code, Python automatically translates this to 3602879701896397/2^55, a.k.a. 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, which can be represented in binary. Python is then faced with a question of how to display 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 when you print it.

Python has two ways to produce string representations of things: `str` and `repr`. In Python 2, the implementations of `str` and `repr` make different choices for how to display floats. Neither produces an exact representation. Instead, `str` truncates the string to 12 digits, which hides a bit of rounding error at the cost of displaying some very close floats as the same, while `repr` truncates to 17 digits, enough that different floats will always display differently.

When you `print` a float, Python uses `str`. This means that your `print start` statements make it look like your `correct` works. However, when you `print` a list, the list's implementation of `str` uses `repr` on its contents (for good reasons I won't go into here), so `print`ing the list shows that your `correct` didn't actually produce the numbers you wanted; if your `correct` had produced the number that `0.3` in Python source code produces, then Python would have displayed it as `0.3`.

Answer (score 1):

use round() instead of *correct* produce what you want:

```
    start = round(start + stepsize, 1)
```

round() is a built-in function:

```
round(...)
    round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number

    Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
    This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may be negative.
```

So I guess there maybe something wrong with the *correct* function

Comment: That's helpful, but I really want to understand *why* this is happening.

Comment: When we print a float, it default to print the float in precision '0.1' so you thought the _correct_ works. You should use `print '%.20f' % start` instead.

Comment: Do not use float('0.3') to get what you want, you can try `print '%.20f' % float("0.3")`

Answer (score 1):

I guess what is happening here is, that `print` is working properly and showing the rounded value and your function does not.

It is very simple to explain: While it is possible to convert a float into string with the proper (rounded) value, you can not store some floating point values in a float. So, your `correct()` can not correct the value and return a float, it will have the same problem.

Comment: I see. Then, suppose I declare the list `[0.1,0.2,float("0.3"),0.4]`. I can print it, and this yields `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`. Why am I getting that instead of  `[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000004, 0.4]`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a FAQ, but I could not find an answer relevant for your question.

Python (and almost all languages use [IEE764](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for representing floating point arythmetics. That means that our clean and neat decimals (0.3, 0.2, 0.1) have no exact representation as floats. Only numbers composed with negative powers of 2 can : 0.5, 0.25, 0.75 have exact representations. So when you try to round or truncate it, the processor does it best and gives you back the number closest to what you ask and that it can represent (about 7 decimal digits for single precision numbers and 13 for double)